# jQuery input field is always validated even when it's not mandatory

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use `jQuery Validate` plugin with `addMethod` function. 1 field is using `addMethod` but it's not mandatory. However somehow that `Percentage` field is always validated even when there's no value. Please assist me with my code. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.validator.addMethod("percent", function (value, element, param) {
    var parts = value.split(".");
    if (typeof parts[1] == "string" && (parts[1].length == 0 || parts[1].length > 2)) {
      return false;
    }

    var n = parseFloat(value);
    if (isNaN(n)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (n < 0 || n > 100) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, "Please enter valid percentage number");
    
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            development_percentage: {
              percent: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: "Please, enter Project Name"
            },

        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="name">Project Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <label for="percent">Percentage</label>
    <input type="text" name="development_percentage" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

input.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

label.error {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: red;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**jsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/xjb4gnyc/

Comment: By default, rules created with `addMethod` are mandatory unless you include a line of code that makes it optional.  Within `addmethod()`, you need to logically compare `this.optional(element)` to your rule with an OR operator.  `this.optional(element) || your boolean rule, etc.`

Comment: You might need to rework it a bit so the logical statements are true when valid, rather than false when invalid.  `if (this.optional(element) || (your boolean rule that is true when valid)); return true`  Search for `addMethod()` on the official documentation or SO and look at the examples.

Comment: thank you. `this.optional(element) || your boolean rule` does the tricked. http://jsfiddle.net/nfp0ugmz/